# fitsSytemWindows inside fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm implementing CollapsingToolbarLayout inside a fragment's xml with fitsSystemWindows, but it doesn't work. But when I moved the CollapsingToolbarLayout to my activity's xml, it does work.

As someone said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190612/fitssystemwindows-effect-gone-for-fragments-added-via-fragmenttransaction), this is a problem when you change fragments through FrameLayout. But I don't really understand his solution that is to remove fitsSystemWindows from every node in activity's xml. I tried that, but now my NavigationView didn't get the overlay effect.

For some reasons, I need to initiate my Toolbar inside my fragments, not my activity.

my activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_parallax"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    //Contents here

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now, if I removed fitsSystemWindows attribute from my DrawerLayout, the fragment (the backdrop ImageView) did went through the status bar. But now my NavigationView didn't.

Thank u for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you facing problem of status bar and toolbar overlap?

Comment: @AmitKumar as I said above, if I removed fitsSystemWindows from DrawerLayout my CollapsingToolbarLayout along with its child overlayed through status bar. The toolbar is transparent though, just like the expected result of CollapsingToolbarLayout. I guess that is what you called overlap?

Comment: Yes I had the similar issue in lollipop,,,What I did was to copy the app theme from style file and paste it in style file of v-21 folder with fitsystemwindow true. That solved my problem

Comment: @Amit Kumar: is your problem solved ?

Comment: @Ramesh_D nope, I had to accept this situation for now.

Comment: @Ramesh_D yes it solved my problem

Comment: @AmitKumar please share your solution