# fitsSystemWindows on API16 device doesnt work

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-support-design, android-drawer

My activity requests layout as fullscreen:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

and in the xml layout sets the *fitsSystemWindows* property to padding the statusbar height:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- The main content view -->

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                    app:contentScrim="@color/actionbar_title_color"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Compiled with `appcompat-v7:23.2.1`, it works well on API21 device but **on API16 device the padding is not applied**. Any hints?

**UPDATE**

***Bounty on:*** why on API16 device the padding is not applied?

Answer (score -1):

From official document [Android development pattern](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.p8oo4s2tu)

> **On KitKat and below**, your custom View could override `fitSystemWindows()` and provide any functionality you wanted — just
>   return true if you’ve consumed the insets or false if you’d like to
>   give other Views a chance.
>
> However, **on Lollipop and higher devices**, we provide some new APIs
>   to make customizing this behavior much easier and consistent with
>   other behaviors for Views. You’ll instead override
>   **onApplyWindowInsets()**, which allows the View to consume as much or as little of the insets as you need and be able to call
>   **dispatchApplyWindowInsets()** on child views as needed.
>
> you don’t even need to subclass your Views if you only
>   need **custom behavior on Lollipop and higher you can use
>   `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()`**, which will be given
>   preference over the View’s `onApplyWindowInsets()`. ViewCompat also
>   provides helper methods for calling `onApplyWindowInsets()` and
>   `dispatchApplyWindowInsets()` without version checking.

Now, You need to check with condition that which api level is used and according to that apply condition like

```
if(API < Kitkat){
    fitSystemWindows()
}else if(API > Lollipop){
    onApplyWindowInsets()
}
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345286/2826147) for more details.

Also read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#fitSystemWindows%28android.graphics.Rect%29

Comment: thus, on API16 should I override fitSystemWindows()?  I dont understand why, as  the default implementation should work to add the needed padding.

Comment: if that is not working than you need to apply condion that if api is this(KitKat or below) that code for that else code for api level Lollipop

Comment: thanks, I know all these posts, but the issue here is how to get working on API 16 the 'android:fitsSystemWindows="true"' as docs says.

Comment: as i have told you, you have to check condition written in my answer and it will work for sure.

Comment: sorry, I dont see any solution in your code:  `fitSystemWindows()` and `onApplyWindowInsets()` are to be overridden in a customized view to set its own behavior, not called. I have not customized view, I have a DrawerLayout that should honour the request to padding the statusbar's height and pass it to a CoordinatorLayout.