# CoordinatorLayout in combination with CollapsingToolbarLayout, RecyclerView and Fragments issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-design-library

In my Application I have one MainActivity witch contains container for fragments, one fragment - CoordinatorFragment   with CordinatoirLayout+RecycleView and CollapsingToolbarLayout and second - SimpleFragment with one TextView. On create MainActivity I add first fragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = new CoordinatorFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

CoordinatorFragnet's layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0000"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/third"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#fff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/fourth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fiveth_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="RIGHT" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="LEFT" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In using RecycleeView's adapter I replace first fragments with second

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new SimpleFragment()).addToBackStack("TAG").commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

After first initialization all is Ok. I can scroll RecyclerView content and last item fully visible.

[Scroll to last (first init)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3nvN.jpg)

But after moving to second fragment and go back to first fragment, clicking back button, last item of the RecyclerView is cutted on size of not collapse part of toolbar. And there is no ability to completely view this item. All other functionality is Ok.

[Scroll to last (after fragments replacement and click back button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWX6Z.jpg)

Any ideas how to fix this issue leaving fragment based implementation?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Change the RecyclerView's height to `match_parent`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: it could be an issue related to `fitsSystemWindows`. Things you can try: add it as true in the CoordinatorLayout properties, check if true in main layout of the activity and in the second fragment's layout, call `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` on root view of both fragments.

Comment: Or replace your FrameLayout as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34345286/4274296)

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I decided to refactor Coordinator Fragment's layout. Because last element cutted exactly on heights of LinearLayout with "LEFT" and "RIGHT" TextViews I removed them from AppBarLayout, and add to RelativeLayout above RecyclerView. This fix my issue.

CoordinatorFragment's layout after refactoring:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0000"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#0000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"></LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fiveth_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="RIGHT" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="LEFT" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fiveth_field" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think that this is issue in CoordinatorLayout+AppBarLayout implementation. Maybe my anwser will be useful for someone.