# Android NavHostFragment with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, navigation, navigationcontroller

I want to implement new Android Navigation component in my app. As I know, the fragment that is basically used to host fragments ([NavHostFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment)), uses by default FrameLayout. But, unfortunately, FrameLayout doesn't know anythhing about window insets because it was developed way before Android 4.4. So I want to know how can I create my own NavHostFragment which will use CoordinatorLayout as root element to pass window insets downside in view hierarchy.

Comment: Check this article, maybe it will help you
https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-navigation-with-custom-views-c763255c9599

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To replace FrameLayout with CoordinatorLayout you can create custom NavHostFrament and override `onCreateView` method.

**inside of NavHostFragment**:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(inflater.getContext());
    // When added via XML, this has no effect (since this FrameLayout is given the ID
    // automatically), but this ensures that the View exists as part of this Fragment's View
    // hierarchy in cases where the NavHostFragment is added programmatically as is required
    // for child fragment transactions
    frameLayout.setId(getId());
    return frameLayout;
}
```

As you can see, FrameLayout is created programmatically and it's id gets set before returning it.

**CustomNavHostFragment**:

```
class CustomNavHostFragment : NavHostFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // change it to CoordinatorLayout
        val view = CoordinatorLayout(inflater.context)
        view.id = id
        return view
    }
}
```

**However**, you don't need to replace NavHostFragment's default `FrameLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`. According to Ian Lake's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34345286/6272369) you can also implement [ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View,%20android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener)) to intercept the calls for window insets and make necessary adjustments.

```
coordinatorLayout?.let {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(it) { v, insets ->
        ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(
            v, insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(
                insets.systemWindowInsetLeft, 0,
                insets.systemWindowInsetRight, insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
            )
        )
        insets // return original insets to pass them down in view hierarchy or remove this line if you want to pass modified insets down the stream.
        // or
        // insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
    }
}
```